# Does Debugger.Break have any side effects?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, f#

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // this DB call has not been mocked
```

I'd like to place these in code at the site of I/O calls to let unit test developers know when they haven't properly mocked out the call, but I don't want to create new problems.

1. Does calling Debugger.Break() have any impact when compiled as Release?
2. Does it have any impact when executing a Debug build but not debugging?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes. Or to go in to a bit of detail ;) 1. It works for all configurations. 2. It'll ask to attach a debugger if one isn't already attached.

Comment: Don't you even get an exception if there is no debugger attached(since .NET 4)? You could add it only in debug build: `#if DEBUG
Debugger.Break();
#endif`

Comment: @AndyJ I think you're confusing it with Debugger.Launch()

Comment: @OverlordZurg Not according to [the comments in the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/debugger.cs,33).

Comment: @OverlordZurg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_Break "If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger."

Comment: @AndyJ right you are. Submit as an answer if you want the sweet, sweet credit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately for your use-case, it does.

To address your concerns:

1. Debugger.Break will work for any build configuration. Debug, Release, or anything else.

Tim Schmelter had a good suggestion. If you want to limit Debugger.Break to only Debug builds then you can use [Conditional Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

```
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

2. Debugger.Break will have side effects, even if the debugger isn't attached.

If there's no debugger attached then it'll either try to attach a debugger, or send a message to the Windows Error Reporting (WER) subsystem depending on what version of the .Net Framework you're targeting.

> If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger.
>
> ...
>
> Starting with .NET Framework 4, the runtime no longer exercises tight control of launching the debugger for the Break method, but instead reports an error to the Windows Error Reporting (WER) subsystem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Answer (score 3):

As the comments and @AndyJ's answer explain, your program will crash if no debugger is  attached to the process.

What you may want is to check if the debugger is attached before calling `Debug.Break` at runtime. There is an API property for that, [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_IsAttached)

Comment: Any idea how significant the performance hit for that check is? Ultimately I may create a new "UnitTest" configuration if I decide this is necessary, but it would be nice not to have to create a new configuration.

Comment: @OverlordZurg, since you are mentioning I/O sites in your question, negligible. Everything is fast compared to I/O, except I/O. :) And if the checks are compiled in the Debug configuration only, then probably their performance is not the thing to question anyway.